# ntpd does not sync clock automatically

Tags: services, clock, ntp

**Can anyone help me figure out why my clock isn't syncing?**

I can update my clock manually with

```
$ sudo sntp -s golem.canonical.com
17 Aug 08:26:22 sntp[518]: Started sntp
2015-08-17 08:26:22.267847 (+0500) +0.000120
```

The ntp daemon is running:

```
$ sudo service ntp status
 * NTP server is running
```

UDP port 123 is open:

```
$ sudo  nmap -sT -sU -p 123 localhost

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-08-17 08:30 EDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00013s latency).
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
123/tcp closed ntp
123/udp open   ntp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.07 seconds
```

Also, `ntpq -p` comes back with a whole lotta nothing:

```
$ ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 www.amsatfox.or .INIT.          16 u    -  128    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 96.44.142.5     .INIT.          16 u    -  128    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 origin.towfowi. .INIT.          16 u    -  128    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 tock.eoni.com   .INIT.          16 u    -  128    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 golem.canonical .INIT.          16 u    -  128    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

However, my clock always falls behind the official time at a rate of about 500 milliseconds per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `refid` is `.INIT.`, your ntp daemon has not been able to reach the servers.  NTP has no time source to provide time from.  It appears port 123 is being blocked somewhere.

- Ensure UDP port 123 is open outgoing on the your firewall.
- It is also possible your ISP or their provider is blocking NTP access.  This started happening after recent use of NTP in generating DDOS attacks.  I still had service on an IPv6 tunnel while IPv4 access was being blocked.

Comment: `Ensure UDP port 123 is open outgoing on the your firewall. `: I am on a university campus.  Can you tell me how to check this with UDP123?

Comment: Ah hah!  I checked with ITS and it turns out my university blocks foreign NTP server connections.  They gave me the local addresses to use.  Thanks!