# ntpd does not sync clock while ntpdate does

Tags: ntp

My issue is bit simmilar to those below, but still different. `ntpdate` syncs clock successfully, but `ntpd` does not get any data back after transmitting queries to same time server(s). My clock's drifft is 1.0-1.5s per hour!

- [ntpd server always in 'INIT' mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134969/ntpd-server-always-in-init-mode)
- [ntpdate: no server suitable for synchronization found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429306/ntpdate-no-server-suitable-for-synchronization-found)
- [ntpd does not sync clock automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/662517/ntpd-does-not-sync-clock-automatically)

### ntpdate

```
$ ntpdate -qv 194.177.4.2
16 Sep 21:45:42 ntpdate[21836]: ntpdate 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Thu Feb 11 18:30:41 UTC 2016 (1)
server 194.177.4.2, stratum 2, offset 17.656685, delay 0.06981
16 Sep 21:45:48 ntpdate[21836]: step time server 194.177.4.2 offset 17.656685 sec
```

and with more details

```
$ ntpdate -qd 212.33.77.42
16 Sep 21:48:32 ntpdate[21841]: ntpdate 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Thu Feb 11 18:30:41 UTC 2016 (1)
Looking for host 212.33.77.42 and service ntp
host found : 212.33.77.42
transmit(212.33.77.42)
receive(212.33.77.42)
transmit(212.33.77.42)
receive(212.33.77.42)
transmit(212.33.77.42)
receive(212.33.77.42)
transmit(212.33.77.42)
receive(212.33.77.42)
server 212.33.77.42, port 123
stratum 2, precision -20, leap 00, trust 000
refid [212.33.77.42], delay 0.03363, dispersion 0.00159
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    db86ca25.1cf0982a  Fri, Sep 16 2016 21:44:37.113
originate timestamp: db86cb28.8dda4c1d  Fri, Sep 16 2016 21:48:56.554
transmit timestamp:  db86cb16.da7f48f5  Fri, Sep 16 2016 21:48:38.853
filter delay:  0.03363  0.03381  0.03365  0.03368 
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: 17.69400 17.69494 17.69572 17.69653
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.03363, dispersion 0.00159
offset 17.694009

16 Sep 21:48:38 ntpdate[21841]: step time server 212.33.77.42 offset 17.694009 sec
```

### ntpd

```
$ sudo ntpd -d4L
ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Thu Feb 11 18:30:40 UTC 2016 (1)
16 Sep 21:16:47 ntpd[21468]: proto: precision = 2.793 usec
event at 0 0.0.0.0 c01d 0d kern kernel time sync enabled
Finished Parsing!!
16 Sep 21:16:47 ntpd[21468]: ntp_io: estimated max descriptors: 1024, initial socket boundary: 16
16 Sep 21:16:47 ntpd[21468]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0 UDP 123
16 Sep 21:16:47 ntpd[21468]: Listen normally on 1 lo 127.0.0.1 UDP 123
restrict: op 1 addr 127.0.0.1 mask 255.255.255.255 mflags 00003000 flags 00000001
16 Sep 21:16:47 ntpd[21468]: Listen normally on 2 eth0 xxx.116.4.142 UDP 123
restrict: op 1 addr xxx.116.4.142 mask 255.255.255.255 mflags 00003000 flags 00000001
16 Sep 21:16:47 ntpd[21468]: Listen normally on 3 as0t0 172.27.224.1 UDP 123
restrict: op 1 addr 172.27.224.1 mask 255.255.255.255 mflags 00003000 flags 00000001
16 Sep 21:16:47 ntpd[21468]: Listen normally on 4 as0t1 172.27.228.1 UDP 123
restrict: op 1 addr 172.27.228.1 mask 255.255.255.255 mflags 00003000 flags 00000001
16 Sep 21:16:47 ntpd[21468]: Listen normally on 5 as0t2 172.27.232.1 UDP 123
restrict: op 1 addr 172.27.232.1 mask 255.255.255.255 mflags 00003000 flags 00000001
16 Sep 21:16:47 ntpd[21468]: Listen normally on 6 as0t3 172.27.236.1 UDP 123
restrict: op 1 addr 172.27.236.1 mask 255.255.255.255 mflags 00003000 flags 00000001
16 Sep 21:16:47 ntpd[21468]: peers refreshed
16 Sep 21:16:47 ntpd[21468]: Listening on routing socket on fd #23 for interface updates
restrict: op 1 addr 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 mflags 00000000 flags 000005d0
16 Sep 21:16:47 ntpd[21468]: restrict: error in address '::' on line 45. Ignoring...
restrict: op 1 addr 127.0.0.1 mask 255.255.255.255 mflags 00000000 flags 00000000
16 Sep 21:16:47 ntpd[21468]: restrict: error in address '::1' on line 49. Ignoring...
key_expire: at 0 associd 45622
peer_clear: at 0 next 1 associd 45622 refid INIT
event at 0 194.177.4.2 8011 81 mobilize assoc 45622
newpeer: xxx.116.4.142->194.177.4.2 mode 3 vers 4 poll 6 10 flags 0x1 0x1 ttl 0 key 00000000
key_expire: at 0 associd 45623
peer_clear: at 0 next 2 associd 45623 refid INIT
event at 0 212.33.77.42 8011 81 mobilize assoc 45623
newpeer: xxx.116.4.142->212.33.77.42 mode 3 vers 4 poll 6 10 flags 0x1 0x1 ttl 0 key 00000000
key_expire: at 0 associd 45624
peer_clear: at 0 next 3 associd 45624 refid INIT
event at 0 193.25.222.240 8011 81 mobilize assoc 45624
newpeer: xxx.116.4.142->193.25.222.240 mode 3 vers 4 poll 6 10 flags 0x1 0x1 ttl 0 key 00000000
key_expire: at 0 associd 45625
peer_clear: at 0 next 4 associd 45625 refid INIT
event at 0 192.86.14.67 8011 81 mobilize assoc 45625
newpeer: xxx.116.4.142->192.86.14.67 mode 3 vers 4 poll 6 10 flags 0x1 0x1 ttl 0 key 00000000
key_expire: at 0 associd 45626
peer_clear: at 0 next 5 associd 45626 refid INIT
event at 0 91.189.94.4 8011 81 mobilize assoc 45626
newpeer: xxx.116.4.142->91.189.94.4 mode 3 vers 4 poll 6 10 flags 0x1 0x1 ttl 0 key 00000000
event at 0 0.0.0.0 c016 06 restart
event at 0 0.0.0.0 c012 02 freq_set kernel 0.000 PPM
event at 0 0.0.0.0 c011 01 freq_not_set
transmit: at 1 xxx.116.4.142->194.177.4.2 mode 3 len 48
auth_agekeys: at 1 keys 1 expired 0
transmit: at 2 xxx.116.4.142->212.33.77.42 mode 3 len 48
transmit: at 3 xxx.116.4.142->193.25.222.240 mode 3 len 48
transmit: at 4 xxx.116.4.142->192.86.14.67 mode 3 len 48
transmit: at 5 xxx.116.4.142->91.189.94.4 mode 3 len 48
[...]
^C16 Sep 21:17:37 ntpd[21468]: ntpd exiting on signal 2
```

I stopped it with `Ctr+C`. The observed errors seem not to be an issue as are ignored.

```
restrict: op 1 addr 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 mflags 00000000 flags 000005d0
16 Sep 21:16:47 ntpd[21468]: restrict: error in address '::' on line 45. Ignoring...
restrict: op 1 addr 127.0.0.1 mask 255.255.255.255 mflags 00000000 flags 00000000
16 Sep 21:16:47 ntpd[21468]: restrict: error in address '::1' on line 49. Ignoring...
```

They origin from these lines of /etc/ntp.conf

```
# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
```

After commenting them out errors disapear but server still do not receive any packages back. And while server is running, `ntpq -np` shows it is in INIT state (here with different servers pool).

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 94.154.96.7     .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 158.75.5.245    .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 193.219.28.147  .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 193.219.28.2    .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 91.189.89.198   .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

I guess this proofs I have no firewall related issue. I also asked my ISP. They do not block anything and do not offer local time server.

### cron

The obvious workaround I am currently using is hourly scheduled `ntpdate`. However, as explained by [Tim Bielawa](https://askubuntu.com/users/2263/tim-bielawa) [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/26940/595586), `ntpd` *works by adjusting the length of a second on your system by a slight bit so that you slowly get the correct time*, while `ntpdate` may adjust clock backwards, which might freak out some programs.

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
@hourly /usr/sbin/ntpdate -u ntp.tp.pl
```

## Update

### nmap

executed on the server

```
$sudo nmap -p 123 -sU xxx.yyy.zzz.142
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-09-19 14:30 CEST
Nmap scan report for example.com (xxx.yyy.zzz.142)
Host is up (0.00021s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE
123/udp open  ntp
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.12 seconds

$ sudo nmap -p 123 -sU example.com
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-09-19 14:27 CEST
Nmap scan report for example.com (127.0.1.1)
Host is up.
PORT    STATE         SERVICE
123/udp open|filtered ntp
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.09 seconds

$ sudo nmap -p 123 -sU localhost
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-09-19 14:26 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00018s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: localhost.localdomain
PORT    STATE SERVICE
123/udp open  ntp
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.08 seconds
```

Executed on a host in different country

```
$ sudo nmap -p 123 -sU xxx.yyy.zzz.142
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-09-19 14:51 CEST
Nmap scan report for example.com (xxx.yyy.zzz.142)
Host is up (0.046s latency).
PORT    STATE         SERVICE
123/udp open|filtered ntp
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.78 seconds
```

### iptables

Although `nmap` reported 'STATE open|filtered' my `iptables` are cleaned up for the exercise.

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

### tcpdump

Executed while below was running.

```
$ sudo ntpd -d
transmit: at 2 xxx.yyy.zzz.142->94.154.96.7 mode 3 len 48
transmit: at 3 xxx.yyy.zzz.142->194.177.4.2 mode 3 len 48
transmit: at 67 xxx.yyy.zzz.142->94.154.96.7 mode 3 len 48
transmit: at 70 xxx.yyy.zzz.142->194.177.4.2 mode 3 len 48
```

gave this result

```
$ sudo tcpdump udp port 123
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
15:16:29.733037 IP example.com.ntp > 96-7.cpe.smnt.pl.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
15:16:30.733095 IP example.com.ntp > pscolka.of.pl.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
15:17:34.733013 IP example.com.ntp > 96-7.cpe.smnt.pl.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
15:17:37.733139 IP example.com.ntp > pscolka.of.pl.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
```

Here is dump for `ntpdate -q 194.177.4.2`, which was successful.

```
15:31:16.790206 IP example.com.48658 > pscolka.of.pl.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
15:31:16.834517 IP pscolka.of.pl.ntp > example.com.48658: NTPv4, Server, length 48
15:31:18.790268 IP example.com.48658 > pscolka.of.pl.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
15:31:18.834546 IP pscolka.of.pl.ntp > example.com.48658: NTPv4, Server, length 48
15:31:20.790210 IP example.com.48658 > pscolka.of.pl.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
15:31:20.834336 IP pscolka.of.pl.ntp > example.com.48658: NTPv4, Server, length 48
15:31:22.790253 IP example.com.48658 > pscolka.of.pl.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
15:31:22.834572 IP pscolka.of.pl.ntp > example.com.48658: NTPv4, Server, length 48
```

And when I executed this

```
sudo ntpdate 194.177.4.2 
19 Sep 15:36:19 ntpdate[8123]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

the dump was

```
15:36:11.856663 IP example.com.ntp > pscolka.of.pl.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
15:36:13.856654 IP example.com.ntp > pscolka.of.pl.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
15:36:15.856640 IP example.com.ntp > pscolka.of.pl.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
15:36:17.856765 IP example.com.ntp > pscolka.of.pl.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
```

### Remark

While one of many tests `$ sudo ntpd -d` I could observe the below.

```
receive: at 1618 xxx.yyy.zzz.142<-178.39.91.211 mode 3 len 48
transmit: at 1618 xxx.yyy.zzz.142->178.39.91.211 mode 4 len 48
receive: at 1618 xxx.yyy.zzz.142<-178.39.91.211 mode 3 len 48
```

Server `178.39.91.211` is not in my configuration. I guess some other host asked my server 'what is the time?' Meaning, incoming communication on port `123` is possible? I do not have `tcpdump` log for above, but `ntpd` listens only on port `123`.
I have dump for similar event, unfortunately without answer:

```
15:27:29.313748 IP 209.126.136.2.42440 > example.com.ntp: NTPv2, Reserved, length 12
```

I have impression, it is not possible to send out packets from my server on port `123`. ISP asked again still denies they would block anything.

## Update 2

Finally, my ISP confirmed that precedent ISP blocks source port 123 on my IP address. I followed below suggestion from [Bill Thor](https://askubuntu.com/users/2176/billthor) and added NAT rule to my `iptables` which changes source port 123 to another one if destination port is also 123.

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -s xxx.yyy.zzz.142 --sport 123 --dport 123 -j SNAT --to-source xxx.yyy.zzz.142:12345
```

Now, my `ntp` server receives answers from other time servers.

```
$ sudo tcpdump udp port 123
14:31:29.875903 IP example.com.12345 > pscolka.of.pl.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
14:31:29.921176 IP pscolka.of.pl.ntp > example.com.12345: NTPv4, Server, length 48
14:32:30.875809 IP example.com.12345 > ntp.task.gda.pl.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
14:32:30.882699 IP ntp.task.gda.pl.ntp > example.com.12345: NTPv4, Server, length 48
14:32:33.875963 IP example.com.12345 > pscolka.of.pl.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
14:32:33.920863 IP pscolka.of.pl.ntp > example.com.12345: NTPv4, Server, length 48
```

And my `ntp`reports as per below.

```
$ ntpq -np
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 2001:67c:1560:8 .STEP.          16 -    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
*153.19.250.123  212.244.36.227   2 u   20   64  377    6.785   -0.791   9.129
 194.177.4.2     80.50.231.226    2 u   64   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact all the servers are stuck with an `.INIT.` refid indicates you are NOT able to establish a connection with the server.  Once you connect to a server this value changes to the preferred source for that server.

It does appear you can't reach the pool servers.  Try adding a `server` with the IP address `194.177.4.2` to your `ntp.conf` file.

Since amplification attacks became an issue, I've found I have issues connecting to ntp servers over IPv4. I have an IPv6 tunnel that allows me to connect to pool servers over IPv6.

This configuration may work for you.  I've omitted my key and stats configuration.

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

# Use servers from the NTP Pool Project. Approved by Ubuntu Technical Board
pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
server  194.177.4.2.       maxpoll 17  iburst

# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited

# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
restrict 10.0.0.0       mask 255.0.0.0       kod nomodify notrap notrust noserve limited
restrict 172.16.0.0     mask 255.31.0.0      kod nomodify notrap notrust
restrict 192.168.0.0    mask 255.255.0.0     kod nomodify notrap notrust
restrict 2001:470:c3c::0 mask ffff:ffff:ffff:: kod nomodify notrap notrust

# Needed for adding pool entries
restrict source notrap nomodify noquery
```

Some options will cause `ntpdate` to use an unprivileged port which may result in different behavior than if you are connecting from port 123.  `ntp` will always use port 123.  Your `tcpdump` indicate the servers are not replying to your requests when they originate from port 123. This will break amplification attacks.

I've been running into your issue on IPv4 for a while now.  I verified traffic is not blocked when both ports are 123 with the command `traceroute --sport=123 -p 123 94.154.96.7`.  I found two behaviors:

- Servers that are reachable refuse to serve time; or
- A network gateway blocks traffic when both ports are 123.

In either case, time is served if one of the source-port is not 123.

I found a work-around using a second IP I have on the host and ip-tables masquerading.  I use `shorewall` to build my firewall so I added a masquerade rule:

```
#INTERFACE    SOURCE     ADDRESS                       PROTO   PORT(S) 
eth0               192.0.2.4  192.0.2.5:200-300:persistent  udp     123
```

This appears to result in the following rules.

```
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j eth0_masq
-A eth0_masq -s 192.0.2.4 -p 17 --dport 123 -j SNAT --to-source 192.0.2.5:200-300 --persistent
```

I haven't fully tested this, but it is working for for shorter timeouts.

Comment: Thank you. I added `server` line as per your suggestion and commented out any other lines of same kind. Unfortunately, the result is same as previously. In fact  you can find server `194.177.4.2` already in my `ntpd -d4L` log above.
You mentioned that you had omitted your key configuration. Seems like I do not have any, so I will study this topic now and will keep you updated.

Comment: @BCT try using tcpdump for traffic on port 123 when using `ntpdate` and `ntpd`. It may provide useful insights.

Comment: @ BillThor after reading about `ntpd` key configuration, I understood it is required for server to authenticate to client, therefore this part of set-up is  rather irrelevant to my case.
I did some `tcpdump` and `nmap` analyses as advised. Please see updated question above.

Comment: @BCT I've played with my configuration and found that is seems the servers are not serving time to other servers.  I've updated my answer with a workaround using an SNAT rule to change the source port seen by the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

ntpdate uses higher number port to send query. so when port 123 is blocked 'inward', then ntpdate will update time, but ntpd will fail.